# MYSQL on select statement from 2 fields and distinct value

Tags: mysql

```
select DISTINCT leg.destination,leg.departure from trktripleg leg where leg.T# IN (select T# from trktrip trip WHERE L#='10001' OR L#='10002');
```

above is the sql statement i execute...

Find the names of all cities (DEPARTURE or DESTINATION) visited at least one time by both drivers with licence numbers (L#) 10001 and 10002.

Table description:

```
SQL> desc trktrip;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 T#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 L#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(8)
 REG#                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 TRKTRIP_DATE                              NOT NULL DATE

SQL> desc trktripleg;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ---------------------------

 T#                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 LEG#                                      NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
 DEPARTURE                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 DESTINATION                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
```

Some sample data:

Insert data on trktripleg

```
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 1, 1, 'Sydney', 'Melbourne');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 1, 2, 'Melbourne', 'Adelaide');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 1, 3, 'Adelaide', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 2, 1, 'Sydney', 'Melbourne');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 2, 2, 'Melbourne', 'Adelaide');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 2, 3, 'Adelaide', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 3, 1, 'Sydney', 'Melbourne');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 3, 2, 'Melbourne', 'Adelaide');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 3, 3, 'Adelaide', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 4, 1, 'Sydney', 'Melbourne');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 4, 2, 'Melbourne', 'Adelaide');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 4, 3, 'Adelaide', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 5, 1, 'Melbourne', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 5, 2, 'Sydney', 'Adelaide');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 5, 3, 'Adelaide', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 6, 1, 'Melbourne', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 6, 2, 'Sydney', 'Adelaide');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 6, 3, 'Adelaide', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 7, 1, 'Melbourne', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 7, 2, 'Sydney', 'Adelaide');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 7, 3, 'Adelaide', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 8, 1, 'Sydney', 'Newcastle');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 8, 2, 'Newcastle', 'Brisbane');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 8, 3, 'Brisbane', 'Rockhampton');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES( 9, 1, 'Sydney', 'Melbourne');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(10, 1, 'Sydney', 'Wollongong');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(11, 1, 'Melbourne', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(12, 1, 'Melbourne', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(12, 2, 'Sydney', 'Melbourne');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(13, 1, 'Sydney', 'Melbourne');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(13, 2, 'Melbourne', 'Sydney');
INSERT INTO TRKTRIPLEG VALUES(14, 1, 'Wollongong', 'Sydney');
```

Insert data on trktrip

```
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES( 1, 10001, 'PKR768', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-135 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES( 2, 10002, 'SYF777', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-135 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES( 3, 10001, 'KKK007', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-133 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES( 4, 10003, 'PKR768', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-130 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES( 5, 20002, 'PKR768', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-130 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES( 6, 30005, 'SYF777', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-124 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES( 7, 20005, 'KKK007', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-123 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES( 8, 10001, 'PKR768', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-123 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES( 9, 10002, 'QRT834', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-123 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES(10, 30005, 'KKK007', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-122 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES(11, 10003, 'SST005', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-122 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES(12, 10002, 'PKR768', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-122 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES(13, 20002, 'QRT834', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-120 );
INSERT INTO TRKTRIP VALUES(14, 20002, 'PKR008', ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE),0)-119 );
```

***MY INSERT CODE IS NOT FULL, i just copy part of it till 14 records but sufficient for this question. ***

The problem with my sql code is

if i do the following

select DISTINCT leg.destination from trktripleg leg where leg.T# IN (select T# from trktrip trip WHERE L#='10001' OR L#='10002');

without leg.depature, it show proper answer, but if i add in leg.depature, it will create another column for the answer.

means

```
destination ----- depature
```

but i wanna join this 2 answer together and become 1,which will fulfill the following

**Find the names of all cities (DEPARTURE or DESTINATION) visited at least one time by both drivers with licence numbers (L#) 10001 and 10002.**

My output:

SQL> select DISTINCT leg.destination,leg.departure from trktripleg leg where leg
.T# IN (select T# from trktrip trip WHERE L#='10001' OR L#='10002');

```
DESTINATION                    DEPARTURE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
Sydney                         Adelaide
Sydney                         Melbourne
Perth                          Hobart
Adelaide                       Sydney
Perth                          Sydney
Perth                          Melbourne
Brisbane                       Newcastle
Newcastle                      Sydney
Adelaide                       Perth
Adelaide                       Melbourne
Brisbane                       Sydney

DESTINATION                    DEPARTURE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
Perth                          Adelaide
Wollongong                     Adelaide
Hobart                         Melbourne
Sydney                         Perth
Sydney                         Brisbane
Melbourne                      Perth
Rockhampton                    Brisbane
Melbourne                      Sydney
Sydney                         Wollongong

20 rows selected.
```

If i just find by destination, it will be

```
SQL> select DISTINCT leg.destination from trktripleg leg where leg.T# IN (select
 T# from trktrip trip WHERE L#='10001' OR L#='10002');

DESTINATION
------------------------------
Sydney
Adelaide
Brisbane
Newcastle
Perth
Melbourne
Hobart
Rockhampton
Wollongong

9 rows selected.
```

But the issue is i need merge destination result with departure. and also it no longer distinct when i select both.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select DISTINCT leg.destination city from trktripleg leg where leg.T# IN (select T# from trktrip trip WHERE L#='10001' OR L#='10002')
UNION
select DISTINCT leg.departure city from trktripleg leg where leg.T# IN (select T# from trktrip trip WHERE L#='10001' OR L#='10002')
```

Comment: Does 'select distinct ... Union select distinct' honour the distinctness or just append at the end?

Comment: @StephenConnolly If you don't say `union all` mysql defaults to `union distinct`, which removes duplicates.